# isotope filter show all items automatically

Tags: jquery-isotope

I need to filter some set of items in a web page at the "page load" using jquery isotope filtering. there for I'm calling below code snippet in my web page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   //function to generate all the items in the page
   generateAllHomes();

    $('#container').isotope(
        {
            filter: '.singleStory'
        }
    );

});
```

This works only for few seconds. once the page is loaded. but after about 2 seconds it displays all the items automatically. Can some one please tell me what's happening here?

I'm displaying the isotope items in below location of my code

```
<section class="rooms mt50">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row" id="homeDisplay">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And I'm dynamically generating isotope items using below function at $(document).ready..

```
function displayHomes(objectList) {

    var node = document.getElementById('homeDisplay');

    while (node.hasChildNodes()) {
        node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
    }

    //document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "row room-list isotope";

    var finalList = '';

    for (var x = 0; x < objectList.length; x++) {

        var home = objectList[x];

        var elevationPhotoPath = 'https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/elevationphotos/' + home.elevationphotoName;
        var homeAddress = home.address;
        var priceValue = home.price;
        var homePrice = numberWithCommas(priceValue);
        //var homePrice = priceValue;

        if (homePrice <= 0) {
            homePrice = '-';
        }

        var homeName = home.homeName;
        var bedRooms = home.numberOfBedrooms;
        var bathRooms = home.numberOfBathrooms;
        var garages = home.numberOfGarages;
        var area = home.livingArea;
        var floorPlanPhoto = home.floorplanName;
        var builderName = home.builderName;
        var homeState = home.state;
        var thaterAvailable = home.theaterAvailable;
        var alfrescoAvailable = home.alfrescoAvailable;
        var gamesAvailable = home.gamesAvailable;
        var studyAvailable = home.studyAvailable;
        var livingArea = home.livingArea;
        var frontage = home.frontage;
        var contactEmail = home.contactEmail;
        var contactName = home.contactName;
        var contactPhone = home.contactPhone;
        var longitude = home.longitude;
        var latitude = home.latitude;
        var homeDesign = home.design;

        var queryString = '?' + 'homeAddress=' + homeAddress + '&homePrice=' + homePrice + '&homeName=' + homeName + '&bedRooms=' + bedRooms + '&bathRooms=' + bathRooms + '&garages=' + garages + '&area=' + area +
            '&floorPlan=' + floorPlanPhoto + '&builder=' + builderName + '&stateName=' + homeState + '&thaterAvail=' + thaterAvailable + '&alfrescoAvail=' + alfrescoAvailable + '&gamesAvail=' + gamesAvailable +
            '&studyAvail=' + studyAvailable + '&frontage=' + frontage + '&livingArea=' + livingArea + '&contactEmail=' + contactEmail + '&contactName=' + contactName + '&contactPhone=' + contactPhone +
            '&longi=' + longitude + '&lati=' + latitude;


        var bedRoomFilterValue = bedRooms + 'b';
        if (bedRooms >= 7)
            bedRoomFilterValue = '7b';

        var filterString = getPriceBandIndex(priceValue) + ' ' + homeState + ' ' + bedRoomFilterValue + ' ' + frontage + 'f' + ' ' + homeDesign.split(' ').join('_') + ' ' + builderName.split(' ').join('_');

        var homeFrame = '<div class="col-sm-4 ' + filterString + '">'


        //homeFrame += '<div class="col-sm-4 single">';

        //homeFrame+='<div class="col-sm-4 single">';
        homeFrame += '<div class="room-thumb"> <img src="' + elevationPhotoPath + '" alt="room 1" class="img-responsive" />';
        homeFrame += '<div class="mask">';
        homeFrame += '<div class="main">';
        homeFrame += '<h5>' + homeName + '<div class="builder-name">' + builderName + '</div></h5>';

        if (homePrice == '-') {
            homeFrame += '<div class="price">' + homePrice + '<span>&nbsp;BASE</span></div>';
        } else {
            homeFrame += '<div class="price">$' + homePrice + '<span>&nbsp;BASE</span></div>';
        }

        homeFrame += '<div class="features">'+bedRooms +' bed <br/>'+ bathRooms +' bath</div>';
        homeFrame += '</div>';
        homeFrame += '<div class="content">';
        homeFrame += '<p><span>'+homeAddress+'</span></p>';
        homeFrame += '<div class="row" style="height:112px;">';
        homeFrame += '<div class="col-xs-6">';
        homeFrame += '<ul class="list-unstyled">';

        if (area == 0) {
        homeFrame += '<li><div class="icon-area"> <span class="icon_span">'+'-'+' m<sup>2</sup></span></div></li>';
        }else{
        homeFrame += '<li><div class="icon-area"> <span class="icon_span">'+area+' m<sup>2</sup></span></div></li>';
        }
        homeFrame += '<li><div class="icon-bed"> <span class="icon_span">'+bedRooms+'&nbsp;Bedrooms</span></div></li>';

        if (thaterAvailable == 'True') {
        homeFrame += '<li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Theater</li>';
        }

        if (alfrescoAvailable == 'True') {
        homeFrame += '<li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Alfresco</li>';
        }


        homeFrame +='</ul>';
        homeFrame +='</div>';

        homeFrame +='<div class="col-xs-6">';
        homeFrame +='<ul class="list-unstyled">';
        homeFrame +='<li><div class="icon-bath"> <span class="icon_span">'+bathRooms+'&nbsp;Bathrooms</span></div></li>';
        homeFrame +='<li><div class="icon-garage"> <span class="icon_span">'+garages+'&nbsp;Garages</span></div></li>';

        if (gamesAvailable == 'True') {
            homeFrame += '<li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Games</li>';
        }
        if (studyAvailable == 'True') {
            homeFrame += '<li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Study</li>';
        }

        homeFrame +='</ul>';
        homeFrame +='</div>';

        homeFrame +='</div>';
        homeFrame += '<a href="displayhome-detail.php' + queryString + '" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">More Details</a> </div>';

        homeFrame +='</div>';
        homeFrame +='</div>';
        homeFrame +='</div>';
        homeFrame +='</div>';

        finalList += homeFrame;
    }

    document.getElementById('homeDisplay').innerHTML += finalList;

}
```

below is the isotope filter function that I'm using

$(function () {

```
var $container = $('#homeDisplay'),
    filters = {};

$container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.col-sm-4'
});

// filter buttons
$('select').change(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    //alert('JS called');
    // store filter value in object
    // i.e. filters.color = 'red'
    var group = $this.attr('data-filter-group');

    filters[ group ] = $this.find(':selected').attr('data-filter-value');
    console.log($this.find(':selected'));
    // convert object into array
    var isoFilters = [];
    for (var prop in filters) {
        //alert(filters[ prop ]);
        isoFilters.push(filters[ prop ])
    }
    console.log(filters);
    var selector = isoFilters.join('');
    $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
    return false;
});
```

});

Comment: You need to post more of your code. The structure of your page and isotope items maybe?

Comment: I've just added the code I'm using here. please note that the isotope items are being generated dyanamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with the event that I apply the filter. I was applying the filter at the document.ready() but this filter is getting overridden when the rest of the contents of the page are getting loaded and rest of the scripts are getting executed. therefore I've applied the filter as shown below.

```
 //below event listener is included in document.ready()

     window.addEventListener("load", filterData, false);
```

/*function to filter the data
this function gets the parameters from previous page and trigger the filter drop downs change event*/

```
    function filterData() {

//take the parameters from previous page
        var price = <?php echo $priceValue; ?>;
        var state = <?php echo $stateValue; ?>;
        var beds = <?php echo $bedsValue; ?>;
        var frontage = <?php echo $frontageValue; ?>;
        var design = <?php echo $designValue; ?>;

//trigger the change events of filter dropdowns
        $('#select-price').val(price).trigger('change');
        $('#select-state').val(state).trigger('change');
        $('#select-beds').val(beds).trigger('change');
        $('#select-frontage').val(frontage).trigger('change');
        $('#select-design').val(design).trigger('change');
    }
```